# Can I ask a similar question that already exists but it's outdated?

Tags: discussion

I'm in need of a new microphone and while searching for that tag I found this [high-scored](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/169/9356) question.

The question body is almost the same to my situation but I have a bigger budget (60€-70€) and I have a desktop (so I can install a external sound card).

Also, it comes back from 2015 so things had changed in between.

Is it alright to ask another question referring this one or should I go with a bounty there?

---

<sub>**Note:** I could go with a bounty but I would lose most of the privileges.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be okay to ask your new question. We understand that 1, hardware changes all the time and 2, not everyone has the exact same requirements.

Comment: Alright, thanks!